# Exotic keras / tesorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to develop deep model with following properties:

- Input - Matrix 1024x10
- Output - Regression of 1024 values (each value corresponds logically to row from input) in range [0.0, 1.0]
- model aims to determine if certain row belongs to target class (0.0 for no, 1.0 for yes). We can call the predicted values "probabilities".

Below I present test architecture prepared so far:

```
  from keras.models import Sequential
  from keras.layers import Conv2D, Conv1D
  from keras.layers import Dropout
  from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

  def define_model_2D_CNN():
     model = Sequential()
     model.add( Conv2D(64, (1,10), activation='relu', padding='valid', input_shape=(1024, 10, 1)))
     model.add( Conv2D(128, (3,1), activation='relu', padding='same', ))
     model.add( Conv2D(1, (3,1), activation='sigmoid', padding='same', ))
     opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.0005)
     model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
     return model
```

Below model summary:

```
Model: "sequential_36"
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
conv2d_40 (Conv2D)           (None, 1024, 1, 64)       704       
conv2d_41 (Conv2D)           (None, 1024, 1, 128)      24704     
conv2d_42 (Conv2D)           (None, 1024, 1, 1)        385       
Total params: 25,793
Trainable params: 25,793
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Difficulties of this model are following:

- convolution over different axis
- regression with very multiple values
- number of filters decreasing in the last layer (output layer)
- the output layer is conv2D rather than Dense

Basically, the model compiles and trains, but the predicted vectors (on train data) are far away from expectations, namely those have almost constant values.

Fully connected layer is not really an option in this model because the relative information between rows from matrix would be lost in such a way.

I suspect that some problem occurs at the reduction of number of filters, but I am only guessing.
Is there more optimal approach to this formulation of the problem?
Or maybe some obvious error with the architecture?

EDIT:
After switching to "binary_crossentropy" loss it started to work.

Comment: So is this a regression or classification problem? You mention both of them which is confusing, also loss and metrics could be changed accordingly.

Comment: It is regression model, let's call the values in the vector "probabilities"

Comment: @RunTheGauntlet then it's a classification (regression of probabilities)

Comment: Yep, after switching to binary_crossentropy and reshaping Y vectors it works well. Thanks!